# How to add existing SSH key to zsh?

Tags: bash, zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, hyperterminal

I was initially using bash to work in git and have started using zsh now in Hyper. How can I add the SSH key that I was using to push to github from bash with zsh now?

Comment: ssh keys are not shell specific. Your keys should work no matter which shell you use.

Comment: I thought so but I have to put in my credentials every time I push in zsh but not in bash. Do I need to add an environment variable to zsh?

Comment: ssh keys are usually in `.ssh/..`. located. to add a key in a shell - is in real `ssh-add` for adding a key to an ssh agent. then it will be used from `ssh` while connecting to a server

Comment: Maybe Hyperterminal is the problem. I never heard of that software before, but it seems like HyperTerminal is a standalone windows application and not part of the windows subsystem for linux. If so, then `.ssh/` may not be found, because it is not in your home directory (wherever that would be in the case of HyperTerminal).

Comment: well, that explains why I can't find it in Hyper. Their windows support is definitely lacking at the moment.

Comment: actually, zsh is running on WSL so I'm not sure what the deal is. It would create problems if I added a second key right?

Comment: @Steve depends on how you want to use and configure that key. I used to have five keys or so, one per server, without problems. However, having two different keys on the same client that are accepted by the same servers does not make any sense to me. When you have a different `.ssh` directory for HyperTerminal you could just copy or link your existing key.